# spring security redirect by using excel hyperlink

Tags: spring, spring-security

I use Spring Security for my web application
By default, the authentication mechanism redirect the user on the "home", but it's possible to access directly to one screen of the application by its URL.

Everything is working well if you fill the URL in your web-browser.

BUT, if I have an hyperlink in Excel sheet, with the same URL, I get the login page, and then I'm forward to the "home" whereas I wanted to access my specific screen.

If I open the Excel sheet with OpenOffice, everything is working well ; as if I were filling the URL in the web browser.

Here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd  
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd"> 

<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp" use-expressions="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" entry-point-ref="entryPoint">
<security:intercept-url pattern="/css/*.css" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/javascript/*.js" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/register.*" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/registerUser.*" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login.*" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/restore/*" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/customer/**" access="permitAll" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/logout.*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_logout"  access="isAuthenticated()"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/index.*"  access="isAuthenticated()" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/template/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/editor/*" access="hasRole('EDITOR')" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/creator/*" access="hasRole('CREATOR')" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/task/*" access="hasAnyRole('CREATOR','EDITOR')"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/ajax/*" access="hasAnyRole('CREATOR','EDITOR')"/>
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
<security:form-login default-target-url="/index.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=true"/>
<security:logout  invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout.jsp" logout-success-url="/login.jsp"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="userEnvironmenttStatisticService" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled">
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="userEnvironmenttStatisticService" class="com.epam.crs.security.UserEnvironmenttStatisticService">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="notDeletedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="notDeletedVoter" class="com.epam.crs.security.NotDeletedVoter" />

<bean id="entryPoint" class="com.epam.crs.security.ParameterizedLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/login.jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="customPermissionEvaluator" class="com.epam.crs.security.CustomPermissionEvaluator" />

<bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="customPermissionEvaluator" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

Anybody can help me?
Maybe you have any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue on a similar system. Here is how I fixed it and a bit more details behind my investigation.

### How I fixed it for my similar app

I updated the entrypoint so it uses forwarding. Your updated code would be:

```
<bean id="entryPoint" class="com.epam.crs.security.ParameterizedLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/login.jsp"/>
    <property name="useForward" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Note: this requires that your entrypoint derives from [`LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.html)

### More details..

#### Typical flow of execution:

This is the typical flow of execution of a Spring Security setup like yours:

1. Anonymous user hits a secured page.
2. An `AccessDeniedException` is thrown and is captured by the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. That filter adds the request coming from the anonymous user in the session.
3. The security entrypoint (that's your `ParameterizedLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` bean) then redirects the user to the login page. This redirection is done as a `HTTP 302` redirect.
4. The user enters valid credentials.
5. The default `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` is called. This handler loads the saved request (stored in the session in step 2) & redirects the user to that page (again with a `HTTP 302` redirect.)

#### How Excel messes with that

Excel, [for reasons that are out of scope](https://superuser.com/questions/444984/excel-hyperlink-not-redirecting-properly-bug), uses a simple http client before passing the url to your default browser.

That http client will pass the first url that returns a `HTTP 200` code.

The http client will trigger the 3 first steps in the flow, landing on the login page.

Since the login page emits a `HTTP 200`, that is the url that Excel's http client will send to your browser.

The browser opens the login page, but it receives a new session id: it does not share the session cookie of Excel's http client.

When the user enters valid credentials, the `SuccessHandler` is called, just like in step 5, except that there is no saved request in the user's session (that saved request was saved in Excel's http client's session, not in the user's one). The handler defaults to sending the user to the default page: your `home` page.

#### Why does forwarding fixes this?

Forwarding simply handles the redirection on the server-side, excluding the browser/client from the process. So in the typical flow example, all of the redirections are done as forwards on the server-side.

Concretely, this means that the URL will not change. This allows Excel's http client to pass the right url to the browser, allowing your user to complete the 5 steps process without any hickups.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and for me this helped me:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218153

Install the Microsoft Fix it 50655:
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9769998

Answer (score 0):

> Everything is working well if you fill the URL in your webbrowser.
>
> BUT, if I have an hyperlink in Excel sheet, with the same URL, I get
>   the login page, and then I'm forward to the "home" whereas I wanted to
>   access my specific screen.

This is simply not determined by spring. Your URL's must be different, or you session expired.

Comment: no. it is not problem with session. I tried to fill url with session id but it was fail